# webbrowser event in c#

Tags: c#, browser, winapp

I use this event for webbrowser in c# win app.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

I can use this event when the document is completed. I want to know is there any other event available for before that. I mean event for loading the page.

Comment: Why don't you voting the answers body? We spend time answering your question.

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi i tried voting you before you want to tell me. but it won't let me vote till i have under 15 reputation

Comment: Maybe next time body,, ;) Thank you.

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi vote up this question so that it gives me more reputation then I can vote up your answer

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi I marked your answer as the correct answer for this question. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @peter purcell. You are the man! ;D You made my day! Cheers bro...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the owner's document [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx). I belive that `"Navigating"` is the event you are looking for. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) is the document for that. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_events.aspx) you have msdn documentation.

I think that this event is `Navigating`.